# Do these posts meet the criteria for answers?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-answers

Given the requirements in the question posts, do these posts meet the criteria for answers?

1. [@Curiousdannii's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/according-to-catholic-theology-why-does-god-have-an-only-son/36895#36895) to [According to Catholic theology, why does God have an only Son?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/according-to-catholic-theology-why-does-god-have-an-only-son)
2. [@DickHarfield's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37132/within-the-catholic-church-what-are-the-main-reasons-given-for-the-decline-of-c/37136#37136) to [Within the Catholic Church, what are the main reasons given for the decline of Catholicism in the Netherlands?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37132/within-the-catholic-church-what-are-the-main-reasons-given-for-the-decline-of-c)

If not, what is to be done with them?

**Perhaps note this:** *Note that this matching perspectives rule has been the de-facto policy since the first weeks of this site.* -Cf. [this @Caleb's answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/please-help-me-understand-why-my-answer-was-deleted/4215#4215).

---

Image capture of the flag history since @Caleb brings them up in his answer.

[image]

Comment: Note that [I commented](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/according-to-catholic-theology-why-does-god-have-an-only-son#comment102260_36888) suggesting you widen the scope to all trinitarians. [Your reply](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/according-to-catholic-theology-why-does-god-have-an-only-son#comment102327_36888) indicated that I hadn't understood what you meant by 'only son', but didn't say why broadening the scope would be bad.

Comment: *Note that I commented suggesting you widen the scope to all trinitarians.* - That was not the scope I wanted.

Comment: Altering question scopes based on community feedback is a normal process for stack exchange. Questions belong to us all. Just because a question can be narrowed to a single denomination doesn't mean it should be. If someone essentially copied your question and broadened it to all trinitarians then yours would be closed as a duplicate. That means it might be better to just make yours broader to start with.

Comment: @curiousdannii I disagree because of ALL my posts that have either been put on hold, deleted, marked duplicate, given heat, etc., after following the approach you outline in your comment. I will let other weigh in because the comment you make is incredible to me.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of these are great answers per-se but neither are they flagrantly out of place. Neither of them exhibit the classic NAA symptoms we deal with a lot around here and neither one seems to be in need of moderator intervention.

1. While the question mentions Catholicism it actually covers a lot of topical ground common to Trinitarians. While the answer only covers the Trinitarian part the OP clearly thought it applied to the question that was asked. If it is inaccurate in its representation that's something for voters to evaluate, not moderators. NAA that a moderator would intervene for would have been, for example, an a non trinitarian answer that argued against the doctrine in question.
2. While not directly citing sources, it does give an overview of the issue developed at least in part from the requested perspective.

I could imagine much more useful answers to both questions but usefulness and accuracy are for votes to judge not for moderators to dictate.

P. S. Please stop flagging the same things multiple times...and keep an eye on your flag history so you learn when you are flagging the wrong sort of things.